# Find a column that only contains a 1 Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I know that there is the command

```
    A(:, find(sum(abs(A)) == 1)) = []
```

and that will find which columns summed up equals one and then removes them.  This is not what I am looking for because if a row contains a 2 and a -1 it will remove that row.  But I am trying to find a column that contains all zeros and a 1 and then the command will set that 1 to a zero.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EX:
A column of zeros

```
    [1 2 3
     0 3 2
     0 1 2]
```

I want the first column to then be changed to a column of zeros

Comment: Doesn't your `abs` in there take care of the negative number problem?

Comment: No that doesn't work because I only want the columns that just contain a single 1 and the rest are 0's.  That returns any row that the sum is 1

Comment: your command works fine for me at-least. Show us a single example where it doesn't work! I agree with @aganders3

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but if the row contains a -1 then it removes it. Also how would I change a 1 to a 0 to make it a row of all zeros? Rather then removing the row

Comment: @user2942812 *row of zeros*?? or *column of zeros*? Consider giving example in question itself

Comment: I mean to say column of zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(a)==1 & sum(a==1) & ~sum(a>1) & ~sum(a<0)
```

The first statement will be true when the column sums 1
The second will be true when there is at least a 1
The third will be true when there are no numbers greater than 1
The fourth will be true when there are no numbers less than 0

So, only 1s and 0s that add up to 1

The final result will be a vector of 1s and 0s (1==true, 0=false)

To change those single 1s in columns to 0 do:

```
a(:,sum(a)==1 & sum(a==1) & ~sum(a>1) & ~sum(a<0))=0
```

Comment: Ok I got that working thank you...
But then how can I change those 1's to 0's

Comment: A(sum(A)==1 & sum(A==1) & ~sum(A<0)) = 0;

Comment: Just realized that the 3rd condition is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge those two conditions :

```
idx = find ((sum(a==1)==1));
idx2 = find ((sum(abs(a)) == 1));
```

The first one search for columns where their only one number "1".
And the second search for columns where the absolute sums is only 1, so no problem with 2,-1,-1,1 !

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just needed to assign `0` instead of deleteting using `[]`

```
A(:, find(sum(abs(A)) == 1)) = 0
```

Comment: @francesco true. but works for OP's data. in such case accepted ans is robust one.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler expression would be:

```
A(:, sum(A==1)==1 & sum(abs(A))==1) = 0;
```

Explanation:

```
A==1           - returns a boolean array with 1's where A==1, 0's everywhere else
sum(A==1)      - sums over the first dimension of the boolean array: will ==1 where there is exactly one 1
sum(abs(A))    - when there is exactly one 1, this sum will ==1 only if the rest are zero
```